# Power automate get row id of added record in dataverse table

Tags: power-automate, dataverse

I have a power automate which runs when item is added in a dataverse table, I need to get the row ID of inserted item, because I need to process some other functions and then update the same record

Answer (score 0):

Select Get Row By ID In Microsoft DataVerse